# Getting different 404 Error Extensions for the same file IIS8

Tags: iis, web-development, deployment

We have a web application hosted in IIS 8 in Windows 8 Beta Server. When i browse the file from IIS getting 404 Erro every time.

When i saw the IIS logs am able to see different Extensions everytime for the same file i browse.

Sample Error log
**2012-07-03 06:58:14 ::1 GET /ReportViewerReg/default.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+10.0;+Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64;+Trident/6.0) - 404 0 0 18**

2012-07-03 06:58:18 ::1 GET /ReportViewerReg/Exit.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+10.0;+Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64;+Trident/6.0) - 404 0 0 11

2012-07-03 06:58:23 ::1 GET /ReportViewerReg/Print.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+10.0;+Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64;+Trident/6.0) - 404 0 0 20

2012-07-03 06:58:25 ::1 GET /ReportViewerReg/Print.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+10.0;+Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64;+Trident/6.0) - 404 0 0 11

2012-07-03 06:58:30 ::1 GET /ReportViewerReg/REPT_KeyClass.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+10.0;+Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64;+Trident/6.0) - 200 0 0 20

**2012-07-03 07:01:31 ::1 GET /ReportViewerReg/default.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+10.0;+Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64;+Trident/6.0) - 404 0 0 11

2012-07-03 07:01:36 ::1 GET /ReportViewerReg/default.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+10.0;+Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64;+Trident/6.0) - 404 0 0 7**

Why is this happening...the file is there in that location !!

Please suggest your ideas .

Thanks